# Can't upgrade or install software after installing Firefox 4

Tags: package-management, firefox, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix this “E:Type '*' is not known on line * in source list …” update error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-etype-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update)

Recently I installed FF 4 by command line following error seen

`E:Type tu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu` is not known on line 2 in source list

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-mozilla-daily-ppa-maverick.list`
due to which neither update manager nor synaptic package manager are working

Comment: Post the output of `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-mozilla-daily-ppa-maverick.list`

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with the file that tells Ubuntu where to find Firefox 4.

You can remove it with this command:

```
su rm /etc/apt/sources.list/ubuntu-mozilla-daily-ppa-maverick.list
```

After that your system should update again.

To install firefox 4 just copy and paste in a terminal this command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily
```

Afterwards you should be able to install it from the Software Centre, or using the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox-4.0
```

Note that this is a daily build version of a beta software, expect bugs.